# Failing to install Zentyal failing - missing dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, zentyal

I need to setup a Zentyal Server on my Ubunut for School, but during this process I encountered some errors:

```
root@nasr-kmu2:~# sudo apt install zentyal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 zentyal : Depends: zentyal-core but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: zentyal-software but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Due to some recommendations on the Internet I tried the following, but nothing helped.

```
root@nasr-kmu2:~# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@nasr-kmu2:~#
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Now try the fllwing: `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Now try installing it again

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? [It may be the packages arent available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zentyal&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I executed both commands, now same output as before, when trying to install zentyal

Comment: I am using Version Ubuntu 16.04.02

Comment: zentyal is not available in the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. Please edit your question to include a link to the complete instructions that you are following....and why are you using sudo at a root prompt?